# Android: A bunch of short text on each line; text managment

Tags: android, text, textview

I have alot of short text to put in their own line to be display in a TextView in Android.

Like so:

Name: Smoe

Age:  100

Year: 1099

and so on

I have it now in a simple text editor over 50 lines.

MY QUES:  How do I manage it to be efficiently coded and display?  Should I do alot of manual labor and add "\r\n" to each of them and put in Strings.xml?

Or is there a way I can put it in a txt file for it to load it code efficiently?

Pls provide incite and I thank you in advance for help and pls excuse my greenest in Android JAVA stuff. :)

Comment: Are each of these fields that you have parsed or is it 1 line ?

Comment: Sorry, they are one item one line each. Somehow the editor put it all in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a table then. Something like :

```
<TableView>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView> <!-- to display the label -->
        <TextView> <!-- to display the value -->
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView> <!-- to display the label -->
        <TextView> <!-- to display the value -->
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView> <!-- to display the label -->
        <TextView> <!-- to display the value -->
    </TableRow>
    .
    .
    .
<TableView>
```

These tablerows can be created and added to the tableView dynamically.

Comment: What I am asking is I have to display each line in a TextView.  I just want an efficient way to add "\r\n" to the end of each line which I don't have right now

Comment: A tableRow will have one row per line.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load a static text you could put the file in the assets directory. Then you don't have to worry about adding manual line breaks.

Get an input stream to your asset this way:

```
is = mContext.getAssets().open("myfile.txt");
```